# Confusing object reference behaviour in recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have written a depth first search that searches the path in a labyrinth, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177795/python-breadth-first-search-matrix-print-path/) question:

```
# for convenience
matrix = [
    ["0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"],
    ["0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"],
    ["0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0"],
    ["0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0"],
    ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0"],
    ["0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0"]
]
num_rows = len(matrix)
num_cols = len(matrix[0])
goal_state = (num_rows - 1, num_cols - 1)
print(goal_state)


def dfs(current_path):
    # anchor
    row, col = current_path[-1]
    if (row, col) == goal_state:
        print("Anchored!")
        return True

    # try all directions one after the other
    for direction in [(row, col + 1), (row, col - 1), (row + 1, col), (row - 1, col)]:
        new_row, new_col = direction
        if (0 <= new_row < num_rows and 0 <= new_col < num_cols and  # stay in matrix borders
                matrix[new_row][new_col] == "0" and                  # don't run in walls
                (new_row, new_col) not in current_path):             # don't run in circles
            current_path.append((new_row, new_col))  # try new direction
            print(result == current_path)
            if dfs(current_path):  # recursive call
                return True
            else:
                current_path = current_path[:-1]  # backtrack


# the result is a list of coordinates which should be stepped through in order to reach the goal
result = [(0, 0)]
if dfs(result):
    print("Success!")
    print(result)
else:
    print("Failure!")
```

It works as I would expect, except that the last two coordinates do not get added to the list called `result`. Which is the reason why I included the line `print(result == current_path)`, which should in my expectation *always* be true - it is the same object, which gets passed as a reference. How could it ever not be equal? The code should be executable as is, but just in case, this is the output I am getting:

```
True
True
...
True
False
False
Anchored!
Success!
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 1), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 0), (5, 1), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (5, 4), (4, 4), (3, 4), (3, 5), (2, 5), (1, 5), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (5, 6)]
```

As should be clear from the output, the function can only have anchored if the last state was `(7, 7)`, which is, together with `(6, 7)`, not present in the `result` variable. I am stupefied as to why.

edit: The coordinate `(5, 6)`, which is present in the `result` list, should not be there. It is the last position from which the algorithm backtracks, the dead-end just before reaching the goal state. I have, again, no clue why it was not properly removed from both lists during the backtracking step.

Comment: You should have some debugging tracing output to show us.  *How* are you mystified?  We shouldn't have to repeat your diagnostic runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_path = current_path[:-1]` creates a new list, and binds the name `current_path` to this newly created list. At that stage, it is no longer the same list as `result`. Look at the list method `pop()` instead.